# hash(): Unknown hashing algorithm: fnv1a64

Tags: php, algorithm, hash, localhost

i have strange problem and cant find solution in google, i have php script and im getting that error.

on my server there are:
1. Centos 7 64bit
2. Vesta CP
and php version

> PHP 5.5.28 (cli) (built: Aug  6 2015 08:53:05)
>   Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
>   Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies

Im getting that error

> hash(): Unknown hashing algorithm: fnv1a64

here is code example

```
if (!empty($settings)) {
        return hash('fnv1a64', trim($settings->purchase_code));
    }
```

Comment: Run `hash_algos()` to see what you have available.

Comment: already run and i dont have that algo available and is it possible to enable/install that algo? i have root access on my server

Comment: Is this your code? If so, why did you pick `'fnv1a64'` as argument to `hash()` in the first place? If not, can you explain where you got this code?

Comment: i purchase script from codecanyon and author has that code to verify purchase code and thats because i cant remove it, if i remove that script not working

Comment: PHP 5.5 has been end of life more than two years now. Stop using it, it's unsafe.

Comment: i upgraded to 5.6, but still have same issue hash(): Unknown hashing algorithm: fnv1a64

Comment: @LashaPareshishvili If you're running off of localhost, did you restart after doing that upgrade? Or is this hosted?

Comment: i just restart server and everything working fine HASH also working, thanks dude <3

Comment: I take it that that ^ was meant for me. Great and welcome. Remember to use @member to ping someone directly as I did for you.

Comment: you both guys thanks a lot <3 (okay i will @member other time)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fnv1a64` hash was not added until [5.6.0](https://3v4l.org/VRm0u). You can use `fnv164` however.

See the [changelog](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php) referencing bug [66698](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=66698).

Comment: so without upgrading from 5.5 to 5.6 i have no way yes?

Comment: You might try applying the patch from the bug ticket and recompiling 5.5.28 from source, but considering that 5.5 was end-of-lifed over two years ago, you should upgrade.

Comment: i just upgrade to 5.6 but still have same problem hash(): Unknown hashing algorithm: fnv1a64, is there way to resolve that?

Comment: now its okay, i restart my server and hash working fine! thanks!!

Comment: @LashaPareshishvili So now it works. Was this based on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53308699/hash-unknown-hashing-algorithm-fnv1a64#comment93499031_53308699) I left under your question? Edit: Seeing your comment, that's what it was.

Comment: OK great, I was expecting the old, "I can't upgrade because reasons." Nice to hear the flip side. Now go to 7.2. :)